# Write Html Img id with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to write

```
<img src="image/#######.jpg" id="#######" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
```

On my html page either from a file php or javascript json file.
The ####### could be any name that gets changed frequently.
There would be 100's of similar pages that's why I need to do it on the fly from an external file, instead of rewriting all those pages.
The id then gets accessed by javascript that matches it to a json file that uses it later in canvas.

Hope I haven't confused anyone.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this

```
var newImage = #########;
var Ids = "####";
document.getElementById(Ids).src="../template/" + newImage + ".jpg";
```

Since you mentioned that there may be 100's, so you have to *iterate the json and frame the code to act dynamically.*

Hope you got an idea.

**Update:**

```
var idAndImageSrc = "#######";
document.getElementById("previousStaticImgId").setAttribute("id", idAndImageSrc)
                                   .src="../template/" + idAndImageSrc + ".jpg";
```

Comment: Thanks but that would change the source of the image only and not the id.
The id needs to be the same name as the image since it is later used to point to another webpage.
Is there a way to write that one line into html via javascript

Comment: @GaryOwainJones you mean, change the id = imageSrc = "####" and change the id as well as the image.  Correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: I want to name the id the same as the image but since they change often on many similar pages want to automate it via script either have the accompanying json file accessed, read and the name written to the html file or use a php file to write the name as a variable.

Comment: Brilliant Thanks user1671639